# Zend - Basic auth in Apache using LDAP

Tags: apache, zend-framework, ldap, authentication

Im new to Zend and to LDAP so I've got real stack overflow...
What I have:

- LDAP-server
- Apache-server
- Zend-application

What I need:

- On any page of the app while user is
  not authorized show Apache's
  basic-auth prompt
- If login and
  password are correct on LDAP-server then
  redirect to index-controller.

I've read tons of manuals about Zend_Auth, about authnz_ldap_module etc but couldnt solve the given task.
Any help - examples, solutions, links - would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthType basic                                                                                           
AuthName "Secure Login"                                                                           
AuthBasicProvider ldap                                                                            
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.example.com/ou=People,dc=exmaple,dc=com?uid?sub".
```

Add that to your directory directive this will cover your need for ldap auth. But you still will need to figure how to redirect freshly coming visitor to index, probably cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked through the whole ACL process and am happy with the result.  Here's what I implemented:

1. Extend `Zend_ACL` and use its constructor to add your roles (including inheritance relationships).
2. Create an action helper which is loaded in the bootstrap.  (You need to load it early so that you can make use of its hooks such as `preDispatch`).
3. Edit the `init()` of each controller that you want to protect and call the new ACL helper, passing in the rules that you want applied to this controller, e.g: `allow('member', 'edit);`

The real work is done by the action helper.  It has four functions:

- `init()` - Instantiates your new ACL class, then adds a new resource which mirrors the name of the current controller, 
  ie. `$this->_resource = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName())`.
- `preDispatch()` - Gets the current user type using `Zend_Auth` (or assigns a default of guest where user is not logged in).  Checks if the request is allowed using the ACL, 
  i.e. `$this->_acl->isAllowed($currentRole, $resource, $action)`.  
  **Note** that the requested action becomes the ACL privilege.
- `allow()` - This just proxies through to the `allow()` function on the ACL object.  It's called by the controller constructor to set the rules in the ACL.
- `deny()` - As for allow.

So, at runtime, the series of events is as follows:

- action helper is loaded in the bootstrap.  This a) instantiates the custom ACL object, which sets its own roles, then b) adds the current controller name as a resource.
- Controllers `init()` is run.  It calls the helper's `allow()` and `deny()` methods to set the rules.
- The helper's `preDispatch()` is run, and if `!isAllowed()`, the user is redirected.

I was auth'ing against a DB, but the same logic would apply if you were using `LDAP`.  (Is Apache's basic auth-prompt the default challenge in this case?  If not, that may add an additional complication).

I adapted this from the book by Rob Allen (Zend Framework in Action), and various other sources.  Note that some Zend professionals recommend an ACL based on Models (not Controller Actions).  I'll give this some thought too down the track.

One particularly handy aspect of the above approach is that it's really easy to maintain ACL rules on an ongoing basis.  While you are working on a particular controller you set up its `ACL` rules in the `init()`.

Comment: thank you for such detailed answer, but Im not sure I need ACL - I have an intranet application and all I need is to get user information from LDAP via auth. And what about "basic Apache auth" - its required cause of some conditions (Kerberos is next task).